# Retrieval of Azure Runbook schedules list having a particular schedule triggered on a weekly basis generates an error

Tags: azure, azure-automation, azure-scheduler

I've recently created a runbook schedule which is executed periodically - every 1 week on Monday without expiry date.
The creation of schedule was flawless.
However when i want to retrieve a list of all runbook schedules using the powershell cmdlet

```
Get-AzureAutomationSchedule -AutomationAccountName $automationAccountName 
i get an error message:
Get-AzureAutomationSchedule : Nie można znaleźć żądanej wartości 'Week'. (The value 'Week' could not be found)
+  Get-AzureAutomationSchedule -AutomationAccountName $automationAccoun ...
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzureAutomationSchedule], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Automation.Cmdlet.GetAzureAutomationSchedule
```

When i remove this particular schedule the full list of available schedules appears.

I've got also schedules than run on hourly/daily basis and they do not generate such problems.

Any help would be much appreciated.

After running the command `Get-AzureRmAutomationSchedule -Name name_of_the_failing_schedule` as suggested by @4c74356b41 i get the same error message.

Below u can see the body of http response after running the cmdlet in debug mode

```
{
  "id": "/subscriptions/XXXXXXXXX",
  "name": "orphaned objects",
  "properties": {
    "description": "",
    "startTime": "2016-11-28T09:00:00+01:00",
    "startTimeOffsetMinutes": 0.0,
    "expiryTime": "9999-12-31T23:59:59.9999999+01:00",
    "expiryTimeOffsetMinutes": 0.0,
    "isEnabled": true,
    "nextRun": "2016-11-28T09:00:00+01:00",
    "nextRunOffsetMinutes": 0.0,
    "interval": 1,
    "frequency": "Week",
    "creationTime": "2016-11-22T10:41:49.433+01:00",
    "lastModifiedTime": "2016-11-22T10:41:49.433+01:00",
    "timeZone": "UTC",
    "advancedSchedule": {
      "monthDays": null,
      "monthlyOccurrences": null,
      "weekDays": [
        "Monday"
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: whats the output of the `Get-AzureAutomationSchedule -AutomationAccountName $automationAccountName -debug`?

Comment: In the debug mode the HTTP response section shows in the body the details of the given schedule but the execution ends with the same error message: Nie można znaleźć żądanej wartości 'Week'. (**The value 'Week' could not be found**)

Comment: try `Get-AzureRmAutomationSchedule -Name name_of_the_failing_schedule`?

Comment: well, in that case, I suppose you would need to contact support (or you could try deleting the schedule and recreating it, but try using other method, say if you created it with Powershell, create it with Portal; or vice versa)

Comment: i've done that, too. I'll porbably return to the daily execution of this schedule.... ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the effort, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the same error on older versions of the AzureRM.Automation PowerShell module:

```
PS C:\Users\Joe> Get-AzureRmAutomationSchedule -Name Every1WeekOnMonday -AutomationAccountName DemoAccount -ResourceGroupName DemoGroup
Get-AzureRmAutomationSchedule : Requested value 'Week' was not found.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-AzureRmAutomationSchedule -Name Every1WeekOnMonday -AutomationAcc ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzureRmAutomationSchedule], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Automation.Cmdlet.GetAzureAutomationSchedule


PS C:\Users\Joe> Get-Module -Name AzureRM.Automation

ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands                                                       
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------                                                       
Manifest   1.0.4      AzureRM.Automation                  {Export-AzureRmAutomationDscConfiguration, Export-AzureRmAutomationD...
```

Upgrading to the latest version of the AzureRM PowerShell cmdlets fixes this:

```
PS C:\Users\Joe> Get-AzureRmAutomationSchedule -Name Every1WeekOnMonday -AutomationAccountName DemoAccount -ResourceGroupName DemoGroup


StartTime              : 11/22/2016 6:44:00 PM -08:00
ExpiryTime             : 12/31/9999 3:59:00 PM -08:00
IsEnabled              : True
NextRun                : 11/28/2016 6:44:00 PM -08:00
Interval               : 1
Frequency              : Week
MonthlyScheduleOptions : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Automation.Model.MonthlyScheduleOptions
WeeklyScheduleOptions  : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Automation.Model.WeeklyScheduleOptions
TimeZone               : America/Los_Angeles
ResourceGroupName      : DemoGroup
AutomationAccountName  : DemoAccount
Name                   : Every1WeekOnMonday
CreationTime           : 11/22/2016 6:15:08 PM -08:00
LastModifiedTime       : 11/22/2016 6:15:08 PM -08:00
Description            : 




PS C:\Users\Joe>  Get-Module -Name AzureRM.Automation

ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands                                                       
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------                                                       
Manifest   2.3.0      AzureRM.Automation                  {Export-AzureRmAutomationDscConfiguration, Export-AzureRmAutomationD...
```

So you can resolve this issue by [upgrading to the latest version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/powershell-install-configure) of the AzureRM PowerShell cmdlets.

Comment: Hi, the upgrade actually solved the problem! Thank you very much for your help!!!

Comment: Please upvote helpful answers to help others in the future with the same issue

Comment: I upvoted the relevant answer, but since i'm a newbie it doesn't take any effects... Sorry

Comment: You should be able to 'mark it as answer' even as a new account